# Has_many through and belongs to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, entity-relationship, has-many-through

I am working on a Rails app where a User can create a magazine and another user can subscribe to that magazine. I want to know the best way to do this.

Currently I have a subscription model that builds from current user when created and users the current magazine as the magazine_id. This allow me to have a table of user_ids and magazine_ids. This allows me to see all the subscriptions but it means I cant easily check all the magazines someone subscribes to or check all the subscribers of a magazine.

When I try to use has_many :through, it throws up an error with building from current user. I have put in the relevant code below, hopefully it covers it all and thanks in advance.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :magazines
  has_many :subscriptions

end
```

Subscription model:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :magazine
end
```

Magazine model:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :subscrptions
    has_many :users
end
```

The snippet of code from the subscription controller that throws up the error when I use has many through

```
  def new
        @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.build

        @sub = Sub.find(params[:sub_id])

    end
```

Hopefully that is enough for someone to figure out, if not please ask me for the other code or information.

[image: Error]

Comment: Please post the error with complete error log

Comment: I added a screen shot of the error page is that enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, you're just missing the connection. **Magazine** can see **Subscription** because **Subscription** has its `magazine_id`. **User** can see **Subscription** because **Subscription** has its `user_id`. Through the **Subscription**, **Magazine** and **User** can see each other. So you want to user `through`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :magazines, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :magazine
end

class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
end
```

If this doesn't work, make sure you post your schema.rb/relevant fields from the tables you mentioned.

Comment: Dude thank you so much, I spent ages trying to figure out why it wouldnt work when it should have. I knew it would have been something small :D. So now I can find out find out all the magazines a user subscribes to by doing user.magazines?

Comment: Yep! And you can get all the users subscribed to a magazine by doing `magazine.users`

Comment: Hey, Just one more question, is there a way to stop redundancy/duplicates, because right now there can be multiple entries with the same user and magazine id in them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work, might need to set additional options though.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :magazines
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_magazines, through: :subscriptions, source: :magazine

end
```

Subscription model:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :magazine
end
```

Magazine model:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :subscriptions
    has_many :subscribed_users, through: :subscriptions, source: :user
end
```

Edit: Needed source, not class_name

Comment: I tried using this code but get the same error, I have added a screenshot of the error page. I have a feeling it is something fairly basic that I have just missed, but I can't see it.